# Yii Model Relation 'on' option to join the tables in yii Model relation

Tags: php, mysql, yii

What is going on with me on Yii model Relation !
I have 2 Models:

```
  `Question and Video`,
```

I am saving

```
`question_id` in `Video model as foreign key`,
```

Now I want to build a relation in `Question model` like this:

```
      'video'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Video', '', 'on'=>'video.question_id=id'),
```

and then in clistview I am showing :

```
    if (!empty($data->video))
    echo CHtml::encode($data->video->video_title);
```

but nothing happen there, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your relation setup incorrectly:

```
'video'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Video', 'question_id'),
//this compares Video->question_id to Question->primary_key
```

You don't need to specify `on`, it uses the third criteria `question_id` and compares it to the primary key of your Question model since you are specifying `HAS_MANY`. If you had a relation of `BELONGS_TO` the third criteria refers to the attribute in that model and compares it to the foreign key in the other model. So if you had the opposite relationship setup on your `Video` model it would be:

```
'question'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Question','question_id'),
//this compares Video->question_id to Question->primary_key
```

Also you currently have

```
echo CHtml::encode($data->video->video_title);
```

Since you are specifying that it `HAS_MANY` `$data->video` will be an array of Video instances. So you have two options just use the first element in the array `data->video[0]->video_title` or convert `HAS_MANY` into `HAS_ONE` then it will only make one connection and not look for multiples.

Comment: nothing happen, maybe yii not supported this type of relation!

Comment: Yes it supports it. What happens if you do a `print_r` or `var_dump` on your `$data->video`?

Comment: What is `$data->id` equal to? Are you sure you have a `Video` with with a `question-id` equal to your `$data->id`?

Comment: yes I have double check, my $data-id = 16 and in video table question_id=16

Comment: If you create a new instance somewhere else and just say `$model = Question::model()->findByPk(16);` then do a `print_r` or a `var_dump` on `$model->video` is it still null?